# Access dropping SQL connection

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, database-connection

Not sure if this is the correct forum for this, but here goes.
Im looking for any suggestions as to what I can try to reslove this...

I have an Access 2003 front end (on each client) with SQL 2008 database. Ive went round each user and set up the odbc connection on each pc.
for most users its fine and been working well for a year, but for a few every now and then when running a query (either an update or a select when opening a form) the SQL connection seems to have been dropped and they cant go any further.
I cant think of any glaring difference between those who have it working and those who dont.
Any idea's where I should start with this?

thanks

Comment: Does your code get an error when it tries to reconnect?

Comment: Yep, dont have it to hand though, will post it up as soon as I can, from what I remember its just a ODBC connection error - thanks

Comment: Do they ever get reconnected? Does it get fixed by reloading Acces or rebooting the PC?

Comment: sometimes its sporadic - a reboot is required and it seems ok, sometimes it seems to happen at the same place in the system, eg opening a particular form will throw an odbc conn. error on a particular table all the time, but again only on some machines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had such cases before: Access frontend, SQL Server backend. On *one* or *some* of the customer's PCs, the connection suddenly drops (throwing some ODBC or SQL Server connection error). Happens randomly and rarely (e.g. once per hour/day/week), and the Access application needs to be restarted to continue working.

In all of these cases, one of the following was the culprit:

- Broken network cable
- Broken network card
- Buggy network card driver
- Unstable network protocol (yes, this one was in the old days of NetBIOS)

The thing is: **Access is extremely sensitive to network errors.** A simple glitch in the network, a few seconds of lost connectivity -- something which you won't even notice with other applications -- will cause an Access frontend application to lose its database connection and crash horribly. It's very frustrating, because the customer will say "*I don't experience any network trouble with Word/Windows Explorer/etc., so my network is fine, and it's your application that's broken.*" It's not true. If Access experiences sporadic and unpredictabe network errors, it's usually really a network problem.

So, the first thing I'd do is to replace (a) the network card, (b) the network cable *and* (c) use another switch port for one of the machines experiencing problems. If the problems are gone on that machine, you know that one of these components was the faulty one.

Comment: thanks for this - I'll put it to the customers' support guys and see what they think